# High level interface for manipulating fields in docx4j?

Tags: ms-office, xsl-fo, docx, printer-control-language, docx4j

Is there a high level interface to manipulating document fields with docx4j?

The task I am doing is to fill in the fields (and optionally remove them or not - i.e. maybe leave them filled in, or replace them with their value), then transform to xsl-fo, with a view to transforming to PCL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MERGEFIELD, there is such an interface in docx4j SVN and recent nightlies; see [MailMerger](http://www.docx4java.org/trac/docx4j/browser/trunk/docx4j/src/main/java/org/docx4j/model/fields/merge/MailMerger.java)

Comment: I'm reading the code now, and it looks like exactly what I need.